# Sustituir variables almacenadas en mySql

Tags: mysql

Existe alguna manera de poder sustituir variables almacenadas en una cadena de mysql?

Actualmente quiero almacenar distincias cadenas como esta en mysql:

> Apreciado cliente, 
> Gracias por comprar en
>   ".common::getInfoWeb("nombre").". Hemos recibido correctamente el pago
>   de su pedido ".$idc."
> En cuanto lo pongamos en preparación, le
>   indicaremos el plazo de entrega aproximado por medio de un nuevo
>   email.
> Para cualquier otra consulta no dude en ponerse en
>   contacto con nosotros.
> Muchas gracias por su confianza.

Y quiero que tanto la variable

> common::getInfoWeb("nombre")

como la variable

> $id

se sustituyan por los valores que tengo en mi script.

Edit:

Añado el script, aunque no sé si es necesario:

```
for my $st (sort { $stats{$a} <=> $stats{$b} } keys  %stats) {
     if($sta==2){

        $argsMail{TEXTMAIL} = textManager::getText($dbh,"TextoEstado2",common::getDefaultLang());;

        $subject = common::getInfoWeb("nombre")." - Confirmación de Pago ";
        $string = templateManager::getTemplate('cambio_estado_mail', %argsMail);
     }
  }
```

Estoy trabajando con perl. Este script ejecuta una llamada sql y almacena el resultado en una variable de un hash que luego envio a una template para poder construir un email

Comment: Y cuál es tu script? O que relación tiene tu script con este código?

Comment: Simplemente haz un replace...

Comment: Joder, claro... Gracias @JoseD.Jurado

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a @JoseD.Jurado que me ha dado la clave. Unicamente haces un replace de la variable que deseas cambiar por el valor a utilizar y listo. Un saludo